# Spring @EventListener annotation doesn't work

Tags: spring, event-handling

I want to handle multiple events in one class, here's my example:

```
@Lazy(false)
@Component
public class EventListenerImpl {

    @EventListener
    public void handleContextRefreshedEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        LOGGER.log(event.getSource());
        ...
    }
}
```

However this method is not being executed when my application starts.

In my `applicationContext.xml` I have:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="..."/>
```

which should be enough for `@EventListener` to work, according to the documentation.

The old way of implementing `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` works just fine.

I'm using Spring 4.2.4.RELEASE.

Comment: do you have `<context:annotation-driven/>` in your XML?

Comment: @Jens No, but I have `<context:component-scan/>` instead which should be enough according to docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/EventListener.html

Comment: rename you methd to `handleContextRefreshed` see here: https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2

Comment: @Jens That didn't help.

Comment: What means `That didn't help.`?

Comment: @Jens The method didn't get called when the event occured.

Comment: You renamed and redeployed your application?

Comment: @Jens Yes, the method is called `handleContextRefresh` and I have redeployed the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, this remains a total mystery for me. I bet it's some kind of wierd maven/ide caching issue, but anyway this worked for me after several restarts :

```
@Lazy(false)
@Component
public class EventListenerImpl {

    @EventListener
    public void whatever(final ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        event.getSource();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What I found might explain what @moonlightcheese observed:
If the event is published early in the application's lifecycle, it is not sent to the annotated `@EventListener` method. If it is published later, it is sent to the method.

My work around was to ensure that the event is not published prior to the `ContextRefreshedEvent`. I had my publisher class implement `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>`, and published my event from the `onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event)` override. Similar strategies could be used where the `onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event)` override is used to gate publication.

It's possible that anything which changes the timing dynamics of the application startup could affect the behavior one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, and the answer is accepted, but I don't think it solves the problem.  I had this exact same issue and was able to solve it by moving the event listener `@EventListener` containing class from the root of the `base-scan` package to a sub package of that package.  For example:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example"/>
```

Simply create a sub package (folder) under `com.example` and place the class in there:

```
com -> example -> foo (place class here)
```

This is what worked for me.  No idea why it couldn't find the `@EventListener` in the `base-package` root, but anyway, it's fixed.  This seems to be an undocumented issue in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Some events are published before the ApplicationContext is even fully available and therefore the ApplicationListeners may not be registered yet even though they are annotated with `@Component` and  `@EventHandler`.

For example the [ApplicationStartingEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/event/package-summary.html) explicitly states that is is published before the ApplicationContext is available.

The same might be true for your [ContextRefreshedEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ContextRefreshedEvent.html), as its first published when the ApplicationContext gets initialized.